# how safe is it to expose an access token to the client?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to interact with the facebook API completely on the client side a la REST, and maybe avoid the Facebook JS API altogether. I already have an access token for my app. Are there dangers to storing this access token in my JS file?

My access token doesn't have any specific permissions, so I'm thinking there's nothing wrong here, but I just wanted to double-check.

Comment: Yeah, I want to know this too!